# Python 3 Y/N Loop Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to Python, and I'm just having a play with making some very simple little programs to get a feel for it, so probably best to keep any explanations really simple haha!

I'm currently making a little program that asks if you want to roll a dice, rolls it, gives you the answer and asks if you want to roll again.
The issue I'm having trouble figuring out is the following (copied from console):

> What is your name: Nasicus
>
> Greetings Nasicus!
>
> Would you like to roll the dice? [Y/N]? : Y
>
> Let's do this!
>
> Rolling...
>
> You rolled a 3!
>
> Do you want to roll again? [Y/N]?: Y
>
> Yahoo!
>
> Would you like to roll the dice? [Y/N]? : N
>
> Oh, Okay. Maybe next time.
>
> Would you like to roll the dice? [Y/N]? : N
>
> Oh, Okay. Maybe next time.
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

As you can see, it prompts twice when you select N before it closes.
I'm probably missing something incredibly simple, so could anyone advise how I can either **A.** Stop it prompting twice or (preferably for the sake of simplicity) **B.** Stop it asking if You want to roll the dice after you have already selected Y to roll again, and just go straight from the `Let's do this!` line.

Here is my code, any pointers on how to keep things tidier/more pythonic always appreciated too! I appreciated the `time.sleep()` probably look a little messy, but I do like the way it paces things when I run it:

```
import random
import time

def diceroll():
    while True:
        diceyn = input ("Would you like to roll the dice? [Y/N]? : ")
        if diceyn == "Y":
            print ("Let's do this!")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("Rolling...")
            time.sleep(1)
            rand = random.randint(1, 6)
            print ('You rolled a ',rand,'!', sep='')
            time.sleep(0.5)
            again = str(input("Do you want to roll again? [Y/N]?: "))
            if again == "Y":
                print ('Yahoo!')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                diceroll()
            else:
                time.sleep(0.3)
                print ('Okay, bye!')
                break
        elif diceyn == "N":
            print ("Oh, Okay. Maybe next time.")
            break

input_name = input ("What is your name: ")
print ("Greetings ",input_name,"!", sep='')
time.sleep(1)

diceroll()
```

Thank you for your time, and I look forward to learning more :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this section of code:

```
if again == "Y":
    print ('Yahoo!')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    diceroll()
```

You're recursively calling the `diceroll()` function, so when that recursive call finally finishes, the iteration of the *current* call still continues.

You're already in a `while True` loop, so you don't even need the recursive call.  Just take it out, and let the loop continue.

Comment: Aaaah I see! I don't need to call the loop again because I never actually left it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `diceroll` [recursively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

```
if again == "Y":
   print ('Yahoo!')
   time.sleep(0.5)
   diceroll()
```

So you call `diceroll()` and then whenever the user is asked

> Do you want to roll again

You call `diceroll()` again.

Here is what is happening. You have a top level `diceroll()`.

`diceroll()`

Then you have another `diceroll()` under it like this:

`diceroll()`

-- `diceroll()`

And then you have yet another `diceroll()` inside it.

`diceroll()`

-- `diceroll()`

---- `diceroll()`

When you call the `break` statement, all you are doing is breaking out of that inner `diceroll()` loop, not the loop where you called it.

A break in the third row sends you to

`diceroll()`

-- `diceroll()`

Comment: Thank you Matthew, that makes sense! No need to call it again as I never actually left it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would just break out your actual rolling into a separate function in your diceroll() function, that way you won't confuse the paths.

```
import random
import time

def diceroll():
    def rollIt():
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print ("Rolling...")
        time.sleep(1)
        rand = random.randint(1, 6)
        print ('You rolled a ',rand,'!', sep='')
        time.sleep(0.5)

    while True:
         diceyn = input ("Would you like to roll the dice? [Y/N]? : ")
         if diceyn == "Y":
            print ("Let's do this!")
            rollIt()
            again = str(input("Do you want to roll again? [Y/N]?: "))
            if again == "Y":
                print ('Yahoo!')
                rollIt()
            else:
                time.sleep(0.3)
                print ('Okay, bye!')
                break
        elif diceyn == "N":
            print ("Oh, Okay. Maybe next time.")
            break

input_name = input ("What is your name: ")
print ("Greetings ",input_name,"!", sep='')
time.sleep(1)

diceroll()
```

Comment: Thank you for that Kyle, that certainly makes sense to split it out into it's own function!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Object Oriented approach:

```
import random
import time

class Rolling_Dice_Game () :

    def startup (self) :
        prompt = ("Would you like to roll the dice? [Y/N]? : ")     
        if self.query_user (prompt) == 'Y' :
            self.run_the_game ()
            return True
        else : return False

    def run_the_game (self) :
        print ("Let's do this") 
        print ('Rolling...')
        time.sleep (1)
        rand = random.randint (1, 6)
        print ('You rolled a ', rand, '!')
        time.sleep (0.5)
        return True

    def query_user (self, prompt) :
        return input (prompt) [0].upper ()

    def continue_the_game (self) :
        prompt = ("Do you want to roll again? [Y/N]?: ")
        if self.query_user (prompt) != 'Y' :
            print ('Oh, Okay. Maybe next time.')
            return False
        else : return True

my_dice = Rolling_Dice_Game ()
if my_dice.startup () == True :
    while my_dice.continue_the_game () == True :
        my_dice.run_the_game ()
```

Comment: Thank you bashBedlam, I shall have to sit and comb through this, very interesting stuff! :)